# Siamart0516 class and wrong hyperref driver

Tags: hyperref, packages, document-classes, incompatibility

I'm using the siamart0516 document class and I keep getting errors like:

```
Package hypdvips Error: Wrong hyperref driver `hxetex.def' selected! [  }]
```

and

```
LaTeX Error: Command \hc@orgtable already defined. [\ProcessOptions\relax]
```

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[table]{siamart0516}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym,times,tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{centernot} 
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
```

Is there some clash between the document class and the packages? How can I fix the errors? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)! it seems that the command `\hc...` is redefined somehow, have you tried to unload some packages step by step to spot if there is any conflict ?

Comment: Where can the document class be retrieved?

Comment: @egreg The document class is here: (https://www.siam.org/journals/tex/standard/siamart0516.cls)

Comment: Apparently the problem is triggered by `mdframed`. However, the class loads `hyperref` and so several packages will be incompatible with it, as `hyperref` should generally be loaded last.

Comment: @SAM Thanks! I will unload the packages and see what happens.

Comment: @egreg The error about `\hc@orgtable` is already thrown by loading the class, the reason is the local `all` and global `table` option for package `hypcap`, see my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317622/16967).

Comment: @egreg Curious thing is that when I unload all the packages, I don't have the ' command    \hc... already defined'  error. But I still have the 'wrong hyperref driver' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `hypcap` is called with option `all` in class `siamart0516`:

```
\RequirePackage[all]{hypcap} [1.11]
```

Option `all` is a shortcut for the option list `figure`, `figure*`, `table`, `table*`. Also there is a *global* option `table`:

```
\documentclass[table]{siamart0516}
```

That means, the code for option `table` is executed twice, as part of option `all` and as global option `table`.

I assume the global option `table` is meant for `xcolor`, which is loaded in the class file. Then this can be more selectively achieved by:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
```

before `\documentclass`. Then the global option `table` can be removed.
The start of the file then looks like:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{siamart0516}
```

(BTW, the class uses a wrong syntax for the optional argument of `\RequirePackage` after the package name. It is used with a version number, but should be a *date* in format YYYY/MM/DD.)

### Driver error

The error message about `hxetex.def` is caused by package `hypdvips`. The package assumes that the file is compiled with latex followed by dvips. But since XeTeX is used, the package must not be loaded, which can be prevented by the class option `nohypdvips`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[nohypdvips]{siam0516}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the '\hc@orgtable' error. Would you happen to know what causes the 'wrong hyperref driver' problem?

Comment: Yep, [nohypdvips] fixed it.